# Modeling RTS game logic using ECS

Tags: entity-component-system

So I've been trying to make a simple RTS engine for some time and I always hit a wall because of increasing, inflexible and complicated hierarchy trees. I've ultimately found out that an ECS is a good pattern in order to avoid such pitfalls.
For many scenarios I can envision how all things would be coupled, but there are some edge cases I can not manage to figure out.

Let's say we have a simple ECS, which lets us add entities, add/remove components from entities and a system which queries for a set of components and updates all entities which have the respective components attached to themselves.

- Scenario 1 - [Single-Player] Should the player be an entity? 
  Having the player as an entity would mean having a system just for one entity that holds a PlayerComponent...

- Scenario 2 - Tech tree and updates to tech trees?

  1. Tech tree cannot be an entity since you want buildings to have their own tech tree, so it must be a component then.
  2. Tech tree is a component, but then you want the player to be able to research a tech from a tree. 
     So the UI must represent this action as an event which you send to a supposed TechSystem. 
     In the end this means you iterate through all the entities which have TechTreeComponent, to get the one you need, instead of just updating directly through a reference or an ID. 
     This could be solved by having a SelectionSystem which holds a state of selected items, but systems cannot have state...

I probably need a way to send a targeted event towards just one entity or inter-system communication, although the second one can get messy quite fast if I choose to add multithreading or priority to systems. If anyone can provide some pointers and how to optimize the architecture for such cases I would appreciate it.

Comment: What even *is* the player in an RTS game? Certainly not something that appears in the game world. Are you sure you need an entity representing the player at all? What data would it carry? What systems would operate on that data and what would they do with it?

Comment: Indeed, you may be right for this.

I can't think of a solution for the second scenario other than having a state either outside the collection of systems (synonymous with world) or inside the selection system.

Comment: You can have a "Selected" component. Then you can iterate over entities that have both "Selected" and "TechTreeComponent". You, of course, want an ECS that can optimize such queries. Besides, why don't you mix ECS with a Blackboard? I often have the impression that people get hung up in trying to use ECS for aspect of a game for which ECS are not very suitable, but each one to their own.

Comment: I think this is definitely the way to go, but I am worried about adding and removing such a high volume of components. Imagine in Red Alert 2, AoE that for every time you make a selection you have to iterate through every selectable entity and compute if it is in the selection rectangle then add selected component as well.
But I am designing my ECS from scratch based on existing ones like Artemis / Ashley, Bevy / Amethyst, and Unreal behavior. I will add some global resources with restrictions to no be used by systems on the same stage, in order to avoid race conditions and forgo locks.